# mobile web app - refresh question when used from iPhone

Tags: iphone, safari, mobile-safari, mobile-phones

Good morning,

I have a web app that I am internally hosting on tomcat v6.

It is a mobile app that is accessible from iPhones, designed for iPhones.

There is 1 behavior I cannot figure out how to fix.

If you double tap the iPhone home buttom and task switch to another app and come back to mine, a refresh is always done.

This is not the behavior I want and I noticed in testing many public websites that they do not do that.

I even stripped all my css and iphone meta tags in case any of that was causing it but it still does it.

My Title
    
    
        Dummy6

Is it a Tomcat Setting somewhere ?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Ralph

Comment: Is there any javascript in the page that could be causing it? What are the headers being returned on the response?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a thought... try restarting your iPhone.  If you have a lot of pages open in Safari, it won't cache them for as long and will force a refresh when you open it again.  For example, if you open a page, leave it open for a long time (days maybe) and then come back, it'll definately refresh itself as Safari will have cleared the cache allocated to that particular page.  Cache times also change by device (pages refresh more often on an iPhone 3G than an iPhone 4) due to the amount of memory, processor etc.